# Finding shortest path without barriers using the sf package in R

Tags: r, distance, cost-path, sf

Say I have three ships near PNG in the pacific. I want to know the shortest path between all three, while not going aground. This can be done with the ArcGIS function "cost distance" and "shortest path", but I would like to do it in R with the cool new "sf" package. Alternativly using gDistance. Anyone know how to?

Example data:

```
library(marmap)
library(raster)
library(sf)

#Make three ship positions near PNG
pts <- data.frame(nr=1:3, x=c(145,145,150), y=c(-10,-1,-7)) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y")) %>% 
  sf::st_set_crs(4326)

#Get bathymetric data from the area
papoue <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = 140, lon2 = 155,
                        lat1 = -13, lat2 = 0, resolution = 4)

#Turn into raster and keep only depth lower than 0 meter (water)
r <- marmap::as.raster(papoue)
plot(r)

r@data@values[r@data@values>=0] <- NA
r@data@values[r@data@values<0] <- 1

plot(r)
plot(pts, add=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative with the `gdistance` package: after constructing the raster `r` as you do, transform your ships' positions `pts` into a `SpatialPoints` object:

`pts <- sf::as(pts, "Spatial")`

Then, you can use the `shortestPath()` [function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdistance/versions/1.2-2/topics/shortestPath) from the `gdistance` package. The needed input would be a raster with infinite -- `NA` -- cost of crossing for all landmass (which you are doing in the `r` raster). You need to transform the raster into a transition layer matrix with the `transition()` function (some extra correction might be needed, check reference):

```
# transforming it:
r <- transition(r, mean, directions = 8)
# Hypothetical distance from the first two ships:
distance <- shortestPath(r, pts[1,], pts[2,], output = "SpatialLines")
```

Good reference: http://freigeist.devmag.net/economics/683-computing-maritime-routes-in-r.html

Comment: Thanks, but it does not look like it is the shortest distance? https://imgur.com/a/EEAaC7g

Comment: that can be the case -- recall that diagonals are longer in distance. Either way, to make sure you account for that, you can geo-correct your transition matrix to account for that. use ``r <- geoCorrection(r, "c")`` after transforming it into a trans. matrix. The reference I gave explains this and more insightful information.

Comment: Thanks. Also, it seems that using directions = 16 gives a more accurate route.